# How can dualists belong to dashanami Sampradaya?

Tags: vedanta, advaita, adi-shankaracharya, dvaita, dashanami

The title is the question. The question arises with Vijayindra Tirtha and Sri Vadiraja Tirtha. It was Shankara who created the dashanami Sampradaya, right? He wanted to propagate the advaita vedanta philosophy through monks belonging to a sampradaya, right? How dualists can have Thirta name?

Comment: How can a Sampradaya be created by a human being? That Sampradaya must be existing before him and Adi Shankara became part of it through initiation.

Comment: That is not an answer.

Comment: I was not answering :). I was simply commenting on something written in the post.

Answer (score 1):

Dashanami sampradaya existed since vedic era as mula vaidika Shaiva dharma but later it was empowered by Adi Sànkarācharya, the Dashanami sampradaya and Advaita vedanta have no difference, work of Adi Sànkarācharya's disciple Sureshvara named Manasollasa vartika, Padmapada's Shri Panchakshari vidya etc: clearly declare the supreme Nirguna brahaman of Advaita has a superimposed form who is none other that Lord Shiva himself.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).